# getting server name and state using MBeanServerConnection

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx, mbeans

I am trying to get the name and state of the servers in a domain using MBeanServerConnection

```
public class GetServerState {

   private static MBeanServerConnection connection;
   private static JMXConnector connector;
   private static final ObjectName service;

   // Initializing the object name for DomainRuntimeServiceMBean
   // so it can be used throughout the class.
   static {
      try {
         service = new ObjectName(
            "com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.
             mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean");
      }catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
         throw new AssertionError(e.getMessage());
      }
   }

   /*
   * Initialize connection to the Domain Runtime MBean Server
   */
   public static void initConnection(String hostname, String portString, 
      String username, String password) throws IOException,
      MalformedURLException { 
      String protocol = "t3";
      Integer portInteger = Integer.valueOf(portString);
      int port = portInteger.intValue();
      String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
      String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";
      JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostname,
         port, jndiroot + mserver);
      Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
      h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
      h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
      h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES,
         "weblogic.management.remote");
      connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
      connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
   }

   /* 
   * Print an array of ServerRuntimeMBeans.
   * This MBean is the root of the runtime MBean hierarchy, and
   * each server in the domain hosts its own instance.
   */
   public static ObjectName[] getServerRuntimes() throws Exception {
      return (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(service,
         "ServerRuntimes");
   }

   /* 
   * Iterate through ServerRuntimeMBeans and get the name and state
   */
   public void printNameAndState() throws Exception {
      ObjectName[] serverRT = getServerRuntimes();
      System.out.println("got server runtimes");
      int length = (int) serverRT.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         String name = (String) connection.getAttribute(serverRT[i],
            "Name");
         String state = (String) connection.getAttribute(serverRT[i],
            "State");
         System.out.println("Server name: " + name + ".   Server state: "
            + state);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String hostname = args[0];
      String portString = args[1];
      String username = args[2];
      String password = args[3];

      GetServerState s = new GetServerState();
      initConnection(hostname, portString, username, password);
      s.printNameAndState();
      connector.close();
   }
}
```

Here I am getting the name of only those servers which are in "RUNNING" state and not the list of all the servers in the Domain.
Can some one guide me with what changes I need to make to get name and states of all the server in the domain?

Comment: Because the servers are shut down, there probably is no server runtime instance... You can try the example here instead if you want: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2851

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked with some modification!

Comment: Good - if you want you can post the relevant code as an answer and mark it as accepted